# how to group by year of the date and disply in angular

Tags: angular, filter, group-by

Expected UI

[image: The events should grouped by year of the event as shown in picture]

```
export interface Event {
id: string;
title: string;
startdate: Date;
enddate: Date;
}
```

The JSON structure

[
{
"id": "35ed3d90-39fa-411a-a74c-ca63032866d9",
"start_date": "2023-09-09T04:09:23+00:00",
"end_date": "2023-02-02T18:21:42+00:00",
"location": "Itsukaichi, Japan",
"link": "http://test.com",
"title": "Won Ton Ton: The Dog Who Saved Hollywood"
},
{
"id": "fb726e21-48c0-4922-be0f-ba2a974235a1",
"title": "Bonnie Scotland (Heroes of the Regiment)",
"start_date": "2022-08-26T12:54:28+00:00",
"end_date": "2022-11-10T12:05:50+00:00",
"location": "Chicago, United States",
"link": "http://test.com"
},
{
"id": "e98d3470-0d1c-4762-afe5-4ebbf752bdab",
"title": "Client, The",
"start_date": "2022-08-14T22:47:31+00:00",
"end_date": "2023-08-12T04:09:04+00:00",
"location": "Sucre, Peru",
"link": "http://test.com"
}]

Code:

```
filteredEvents!: Observable<Event[]>;

groupByYear() {
const res = this.filteredEvents.pipe(reduce((a:any, c) => {
let cc = { ...c };
["start_date","end_Date"].forEach((d:any) => {cc[d] = new 
Date(cc[d])});
let y = cc.start_date.getFullYear();
(a[y] = a[y] ?? []).push(cc);
return a;
}, {}));
```

Answer (score 2):

The core task seems to be to reorganise your array of objects before displaying it using angular:

```js
const data=[ { "id": "35ed3d90-39fa-411a-a74c-ca63032866d9", "start_date": "2023-09-09T04:09:23+00:00", "end_date": "2023-02-02T18:21:42+00:00", "location": "Itsukaichi, Japan", "link": "http://test.com", "title": "Won Ton Ton: The Dog Who Saved Hollywood" }, { "id": "fb726e21-48c0-4922-be0f-ba2a974235a1", "title": "Bonnie Scotland (Heroes of the Regiment)", "start_date": "2022-08-26T12:54:28+00:00", "end_date": "2022-11-10T12:05:50+00:00", "location": "Chicago, United States", "link": "http://test.com" }, { "id": "e98d3470-0d1c-4762-afe5-4ebbf752bdab", "title": "Client, The", "start_date": "2022-08-14T22:47:31+00:00", "end_date": "2023-08-12T04:09:04+00:00", "location": "Sucre, Peru", "link": "http://test.com" }]

const res=data.reduce((a,c)=>{
  let cc={...c};
  ["start_date","end_date"].forEach(d=>cc[d]=new Date(cc[d]));
  let y=cc.start_date.getFullYear();
  (a[y]=a[y]??[]).push(cc);
  return a;
}, {});

// sort the entries for each year in a descending order:
Object.values(res).forEach(arr=>arr.sort((a,b)=>b.start_date-a.start_dat))

console.log(res)
// res is an object of arrays of elements.
// Each year is represented as a property, having an array of objects behind it.
// It can now be used to be displayed with angular...
```

Comment: I am beginner of angualr. The given answer works but getting following errors. 
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ id: string; title: string; start_date: Date; end_date: Date; location: string; link: string; }

Comment: Yes, in order for this to work with Angular you will need to comply with TypeScript rules. My snippet is Vanilla JavaScript. Unfortunately I have no knowledge of Angular and cannot help you any further here.

Comment: It's only say that the variable is "any": `forEach((d:any)=>...)` and `forEach((arr:any)=>..)`. NOTE: a good practice is use interfaces and indicate the type of variable, but use "any" is enought